# SOLVED - Network broken after yum update (using OpenVZ 7 / Fedora / CentOS 8)

Tags: linux-networking, ping, openvz

I have just installed OpenVZ 7 from the [official ISO image](https://download.openvz.org/virtuozzo/releases/7.0/x86_64/iso/). The installation went well, and everything basically working. I can ssh into the hw node without issue. However, after doing a yum update, the network seems to be locked down and I cannot figure out why.

I am able to ping everything prior to the yum update and only the hw node and any containers after the update.

I have tried flushing & stopping iptables and stopping firewalld, but no matter what I try, I still cannot ping or ssh anything.

Here is what was installed during the yum update:

```
Mar 13 11:11:46 Installed: urw-base35-fonts-common-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:02 Installed: adobe-mappings-cmap-20171205-3.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:02 Installed: adobe-mappings-cmap-deprecated-20171205-3.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:03 Installed: adobe-mappings-pdf-20180407-1.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:04 Installed: xkeyboard-config-2.24-1.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:26 Installed: nbdkit-1.8.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:28 Installed: libXfixes-5.0.3-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:28 Installed: libXrender-0.9.10-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:28 Installed: libXxf86vm-1.1.4-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: 1:libglvnd-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: libxshmfence-1.2-1.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: libXrandr-1.5.1-2.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: libXcursor-1.1.15-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: libXdamage-1.1.4-4.1.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:29 Installed: nbdkit-plugin-vddk-1.8.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:30 Installed: nbdkit-plugin-python-common-1.8.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:30 Installed: libnftnl-1.0.8-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:30 Installed: 1:nftables-0.8-14.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: libXxf86misc-1.0.3-7.1.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: libXi-1.7.9-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: libXinerama-1.1.3-3.1.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: libXmu-1.1.2-2.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-20.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: urw-base35-bookman-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:31 Installed: urw-base35-z003-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:32 Installed: urw-base35-nimbus-sans-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:32 Installed: urw-base35-nimbus-roman-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:32 Installed: urw-base35-c059-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:32 Installed: urw-base35-standard-symbols-ps-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:32 Installed: urw-base35-gothic-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:33 Installed: urw-base35-p052-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:33 Installed: urw-base35-d050000l-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:33 Installed: urw-base35-nimbus-mono-ps-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:33 Installed: urw-base35-fonts-20170801-12.vl7.noarch
Mar 13 11:12:41 Installed: llvm-private-7.0.1-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:41 Installed: openjpeg2-2.3.1-3.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:42 Installed: libwayland-client-1.15.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:42 Installed: libxkbcommon-0.7.1-3.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:12:43 Installed: libpaper-1.1.24-8.vl7.1.x86_64
Mar 13 11:14:43 Installed: libgs-9.25-2.vl7.3.x86_64
Mar 13 11:14:45 Installed: nbdkit-plugin-python2-1.8.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:14:46 Installed: 32:bind-export-libs-9.11.4-9.P2.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:14:49 Installed: geoipupdate-2.5.0-1.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:10 Installed: 1:libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:11 Installed: mesa-libGL-18.3.4-6.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:11 Installed: 1:libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:11 Installed: mesa-libEGL-18.3.4-6.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:15 Installed: 1:grub2-tools-minimal-2.02-0.65.vl7.6.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:17 Installed: 1:grub2-tools-extra-2.02-0.65.vl7.6.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:29 Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1062.4.2.vz7.116.7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:34 Installed: 1:grub2-tools-2.02-0.65.vl7.6.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:42 Installed: python36-3.6.6-3.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:46 Installed: python36-libs-3.6.6-3.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:47 Installed: abrt-addon-python3-2.1.11-50.vl7.1.noarch
Mar 13 11:15:52 Installed: mesa-filesystem-18.3.4-6.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:15:54 Installed: mesa-dri-drivers-18.3.4-6.vl7.x86_64
Mar 13 11:16:04 Installed: 1:grub2-2.02-0.65.vl7.6.x86_64
Mar 13 11:16:17 Installed: 1:grub2-tools-efi-2.02-0.65.vl7.6.x86_64
```

Any ideas what is preventing me from sshing into the server or even pinging outside the server?

Answer (score 0):

OK. After 3 days of trying to figure this out, I found that the issue was due to the network interface being misspelled. Here is what I did to fix it:

1. I tried bouncing the network (systemctl status network.service) and found there was an error in the interfaces.
2. Running the "nmcli dev status" command showed me the available interfaces
3. Looked at my interfaces in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ directory
4. Found that the eithernet interface was spelled incorrectly (enp0s3 instead of enp3s0)
5. I changed the filename to be correct
6. Restarted the Network Manager

After restarting the Network Manager, all works!

Hope this helps someone out!